# Setting anacron on mac - Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting, terminal

I set cron to run script every day using **env EDITOR=nano crontab -e** where I wrote something like this **@daily path/to/sript.script**

Now I want to use anacron to be sure that script is going to be run when I log in if I was logged off at the time when it was scheduled. But I am not sure where to specify that.

I tried something like **env EDITOR=nano anacron -e** but that didn't work. Also, strange is that man anacron doesn't provide anything. I get this: "No manual entry for anacron"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anacron is not an installed utility in OS X. But there are some other options like launchd...